# How to push additional element to Vec<&Vec<String>>?

Tags: rust, vector

I am trying to accomplish something rather simple, but not sure how to do it in Rust.

I have a Vec<&Vec>, something like the below example.

```rust
[
 ["a1", "b2", "c3"],
 ["d1", "e2", "f3"],
 ["g1", "h2", "i3"]
]
```

I want to push an additional string at the end of each vector.

```rust
[
 ["a1", "b2", "c3", "something"],
 ["d1", "e2", "f3", "something"],
 ["g1", "h2", "i3", "something"]
]
```

What I've tried so far is below:

```rust
vec_of_strings
    .iter_mut()
    .map(|x| x.clone().push("something".to_string()))
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

println!("{:?}", vec_of_strings);
```

But the output is showing that nothing is appended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing creates a new `Vec`, it does not modify the exist ones. Indeed, the existing ones cannot be modified as you are borrowing them immutably (the `&` in `Vec<&Vec<_>>`).

Note that using `.iter_mut()` instead of `.iter()` is pointless here as you aren't mutating the elements.

Additionally, `Vec::push()` doesn't return anything, so the `.to_string()` invocation should be giving you a compile-time error.  (I assume you meant to call this on the string literal instead.)

Fixing the above issues:

```
let new_vec_of_strings = vec_of_strings
  .iter()
  .map(|x| {
    let mut x = x.clone();
    x.push("something".to_string());
    x
  })
  .collect::<Vec<_>>();

println!("{:?}", new_vec_of_strings);
```

However, this all seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) -- there is probably a better way to accomplish whatever your goal is.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. This exactly solves my problem. Still learning and getting used to Rust and as you suggested there is probably a better way to do this, completely agree with that. The way I am trying to solve this problem felt weird. Thanks again.

Comment: There was also an extra `)`, so I assume it's just a typo and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, You need to return a `vec` in `map`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut vec_of_strings = vec![
        vec!["a1", "b2", "c3"], 
        vec!["d1", "e2", "f3"], 
        vec!["g1", "h2", "i3"]
    ];
    println!("{:?}", vec_of_strings);
    
    let vec_of_strings: Vec<Vec<&str>> = vec_of_strings.iter_mut().map(|x| {x.push("something"); x.clone()}).collect();
    println!("{:?}", vec_of_strings);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3573d068e9fe584e157f14e6aa0414f8)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a misunderstanding on what the `map` method was made for. This methodis generally used for data transformations where the original values remain unchanged. What you are really doing here is causing a side effect, and the `map` method does not help you at all here.

Just use a `for` loop. It's not like you're saving keystrokes by using map and interators.

However, you mentioned you have a `Vec<&Vec>`. Having this type seems unfit for your purpose. Cloning the entire vec just to add 1 element is terrible for performance.

I see 2 choices: either have it fully owned, i.e. `Vec<Vec>`, or just make the inner `Vec`s mutable, as in `Vec<&mut Vec>`.

This is the first option, and I think this is the most idiomatic:

```
fn main() {
    let mut vec_of_strings = vec![
        vec!["a1", "b2", "c3"], 
        vec!["d1", "e2", "f3"], 
        vec!["g1", "h2", "i3"]
    ];
 
    for vec in vec_of_strings.iter_mut() {
        vec.push("something");
    }
    
    println!("{vec_of_strings:?}");
}
```

If having it in an owned form is not acceptable, then another option is to use `Vec<&mut Vec>`:

```
fn main() {
    fn main() {
    let mut vec_of_strings = vec![
        vec!["a1", "b2", "c3"], 
        vec!["d1", "e2", "f3"], 
        vec!["g1", "h2", "i3"]
    ];
    
    //suppose somehow a function gave you this:
    let vec_of_mut_strings: Vec<&mut Vec<_>> = vec_of_strings
        .iter_mut()
        .collect();
    
    for vec in vec_of_mut_strings {
        vec.push("something");
    }
    
    //notice that the original vec_of_strings change
    println!("{vec_of_strings:?}");
}
}
```

Comment: _"This method is generally used for data transformations where the original values remain unchanged."_ That's not entirely true in Rust. The ability to invoke `.into_iter()` on a collection to consume it, alter the elements (as they are owned), and collect them into a different kind of collection is incredibly powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your output looks like this:

```
[(), (), ()]
```

Here are some suggestions:

- Prefer using [`for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) for mutations instead of `map`:

  ```rust
  vec_of_strings
      .iter_mut()
      .for_each(|x| {
          x.push("something");
      });

  println!("{:?}", vec_of_strings);
  ```

  Note that this assumes that the `vec_of_strings` is defined similarly as such:

  ```rust
  let mut vec1 = vec!["a1", "b2", "c3"];
  let mut vec2 = vec!["d1", "e2", "f3"];
  let mut vec3 = vec!["g1", "h2", "i3"];
  let mut vec_of_strings: Vec<&mut Vec<&str>> = vec![&mut vec1, &mut vec2, &mut vec3];
  ```

  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=33a6bc5765eff4e1d943d57b853ce613)
- The function in `.map` in your example doesn't return anything because `Vec::push` doesn't return the vector.

  Separate `x` to another line to return the vector.

  ```rust
  vec_of_strings.iter_mut()
      .map(|x| {
          x.push("something");
          x
      })
      .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
  ```

  Note that this assumes that the `vec_of_strings` is defined similarly as such:

  ```rust
  let mut vec1 = vec!["a1", "b2", "c3"];
  let mut vec2 = vec!["d1", "e2", "f3"];
  let mut vec3 = vec!["g1", "h2", "i3"];
  let mut vec_of_strings: Vec<&mut Vec<&str>> = vec![&mut vec1, &mut vec2, &mut vec3];
  ```

  [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b37eb50328325dac013887333bbebcd)
- You might also like to be more explicit with the type of the vector elements (`&str`) when using `map`:

  ```rust
      .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
  ```

  instead of

  ```rust
      .collect::<Vec<_>>();
  ```

  which was inferred as `Vec<()>` by the compiler because of the return type of `Vec::push` in `map` (hence the output).

Answer (score 0):

A solution that keeps the original format extending each array by one entry:

```
vec_of_strings
    .iter_mut()
    .map(|a| {
        let mut v = a.to_vec();
        v.push("something");
        let arr: [&str; 4] = v.try_into().unwrap();
        arr
    })
    .collect::<Vec<[&str; 4]>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=7bc0c05086b5bf490027915e44398a7a)